# I need help converting map() into a list() in Python

Tags: python, list, typeerror

I am new in python and I am doing an assignment for class and I get an error after trying to convert a map containing a previous lambda function into a list.

The code I wrote was the following:

```
converter = lambda x: x*2 if isinstance(x, int) else x

print(list(map(converter, list_example)))
```

The error I received is:

```py
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

list_example is a list I previously created.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: That's because you used `list` as a variable for the name of a list. So it's no longer the `list` function.

Comment: Don't use standard Python keywords as variable names. Don't name anything `list`, `str`, `dict`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!  That was what happened

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
>>> list_example = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> converter = lambda x: x*2 if isinstance(x, int) else x
>>>
>>> print(list(map(converter, list_example)))
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Your error may be that you previously redefined the builtin `list` function to refer to something else.  Never ever do this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3]  # NO!  BAD!
```

If you have a line like that somewhere earlier in your code, pick a different name and your later use of the `list` function should work now.